# Is it possible to compose AOP annotations?

Tags: java, spring, aop, spring-aop

So, I have 2 annotation A and B coming from existing java libraries and that implement AOP.

Both of them do something that is necessary to my class and I need to put them in this order (A before B):

```
public class MyClass{

    @A(parameter="par")
    @B(value="key")
    public void method(){

    }
}
```

Would it be possible to define a 3rd annotation, C, as a composition of both?
So in the end I would get:

```
public class MyClass{

    @C(parameter="par", value="key")
    public void method(){

    }
}
```

**edit:** added the requirement of taking a parameter from @A as well and the fact that I don't have the source code as the annotations are taken from libs.

Comment: Which AOP library do you use?

Comment: If it is AspectJ, and you have both aspect's code simply define new aspect and combine the code. If you don't have aspects code, create some simple class with both annotations, generate .class byte code with both annotations and de-compile it.

Comment: It is for 2 existing annotations coming from 2 libraries. I noticed that they work well together if I put annotation A before annotation B so, to enforce this behavior, I want to combine them into one

Comment: Firstly, annotations do not "implement AOP" or anything else, they are just what the name implies: annotations. They just sit there and wait to be read or processed by some mechanism actually implementing functionality. As for your question: In both Spring AOP and AspectJ there are ways to define aspect precedence, i.e. the order in which aspect advices are to be executed. There probably is no need to somehow "combine" them. Your tags imply that you use Spring AOP, but it could also be AspectJ used from within Spring. Many users confuse the two, so which one is it?

Comment: hi, did you find the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on library you use. for example spring does

```
 @Documented
   @Inherited
    @SpringBootConfiguration
    @EnableAutoConfiguration
    @ComponentScan(excludeFilters = {
            @Filter(type = FilterType.CUSTOM, classes = TypeExcludeFilter.class),
            @Filter(type = FilterType.CUSTOM, classes = AutoConfigurationExcludeFilter.class) })
    public @interface SpringBootApplication {

        /**
         * Exclude specific auto-configuration classes such that they will never be applied.
         * @return the classes to exclude
         */
        @AliasFor(annotation = EnableAutoConfiguration.class)
        Class<?>[] exclude() default {};
```

with this approach you would have:

```
    @A
    @B
    public @interface C{
        @AliasFor(annotation = B.class)
        String value();
        @AliasFor(annotation = А.class, attribute = "parameter")
        String param();
    }
```

Comment: @Inherited is not required

Comment: Would also be possible to combine the input of the two annotations?

Comment: yes you would have @C("key") . and this will be exact same if there were @A+@B("key");

Comment: Sorry I didn't explain myself well, please look at the edit I made

Comment: This is what @AliasFor(annotation = B.class) does.

Comment: Mmmm...doesn't work: the AOP that handles the annotation @A cannot see my @C

Comment: Please add more details to your question. create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. what you trying to achieve

Comment: Annotations by themselves are doing nothing. they are only markers or some hints so it depends on library how these metadata is used.

Answer (score 1):

```java
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@A
@B
public @interface C {
    @AliasFor(annotation = B.class, attribute = "value")
    String value() default {};
}
```

Let me know if this works.